# Що означає слово "клюски"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У творі Ю. Винничука "Весняні ігри в осінніх садах" знаходжу таке речення:

> Ні, але я перестав обманювати дівчат, вішаючи їм **клюски** про свої почуття...

Розумію, що це в значенні "обманювати", проте все ж зветаюся у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kljusok), аби з’ясувати семантику самого слова, однак інформації не знайшла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Кльоцки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8) (клюски, від нім. Klößchen) — страва, що готувалася аналогічно галушкам, але з доповнювачами. Прісне (як на вареники чи галушки) тісто замішували з м'ятою вареною картоплею, свіжим кисломолочним сиром, виробляли кульки й варили їх в окропі, юшці чи молоці, поки ті не спливали. На Поліссі готували різновид кльоцок — коми з гречаного, пшеничного борошна, м'ятої картоплі й тертого маку. Їли кльоцки гарячими зі сметаною, засмажкою з цибулі, шкварками, олією, вершковим маслом. Їх і тепер охоче готують переважно у західних областях України.